# Simple mod rewrite query string but still failed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to create .htaccess mod rewrite but still have problem.

Suppose i created friendly URL like this :

**mydomain.com/mypage/12345/title-of-news**

I want that friendly URL process the below URL in hidden process :

**mydomain.com/index.php?p=mypage&idnews=12345**

Values of "p" and "idnews" are dynamic, so they will have different value.

I tried below code but still didn't work. Anything wrong?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(\w+)&idnews=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^index.php /%1/%2 [L,R=301]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if this is duplicated question, if don't mind please tell me the answer link. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wrong. You're writing your RewriteCond as if the QUERY_STRING had already been rewritten. Take this out. Your RewriteRule should be something like ^\/(.*)\/(.*)\/$ index.php?p=$1&idnews=$2

Comment: So you want to redirect the **old** query string URL to the **new** friendly URL, is that correct?

Comment: yes i want to move old query string to new friendly URL.

Comment: Then Ed is right, you have it backwards. You need to look for the new URL pattern and internally redirect to your index.php. Do you need an example?

Comment: yes jack, i need example of .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change `index.php?p=foo&idnews=bar` to `/foo/bar` , try theses rules :

```
RewriteEngine on

##externally redirect "/index.php?p=foo&idnews=bar" to "/foo/bar"##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=([^&]+)&idnews=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R,NC]
##internally redirect "/foo/bar" to "/index.php?p=foo&idnews=bar"##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(.*)?$ /index.php?p=$1&idnews=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It works. But why other format of URL changed? for example : homepage link to "index.php" become "/foo/bar/index.php". How to make other URL format not changed?

Comment: @Harris Do you have any other rules that can conflict with this ?

Comment: oke done. It is solved now. instead of use homepage link like 

<a href="index.php">Home</a>

i changed to 

<a href="http://www.domain.com/index.php">Home</a>

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need the RewriteCond you write there.

And you can use following rule

```
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+)$ index.php?p=$1&idnews=$2 [L]
```

Comment: when i use this method, produce 404 not found page.