# Remove url .php extension and parameters of get request?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My URL is:

```
https://example.com/detail.php?id=56&subcat=11
```

I need like this:

```
https://example.com/detail/56/11
```

Using .htaccess file i am not able to remove the parameter names (id, subcat) and question mark(?). I have removed only .PHP extension.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+products(?:\.php)?\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ products/%1? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

## hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Thank you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JS or jQuery. It's an Apache/htaccess configuration issue, so I've re-tagged it for you

Comment: you want to turn the first URL into the second one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple mod rewrite query string but still failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109639/simple-mod-rewrite-query-string-but-still-failed)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit complex problem. You won't achive it only by .htaccess. You have to parse variables from url to array and make it accessible from php code. In [this link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049) in section 'Using php' there is some example how to do this.

Because you don't want to use "normal" link, we have to handle requests for pages and manually parse them. First define in you htaccess redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Then create `index.php` which will handle redirects.

```
// your available sites
$sites = [ 'detail' ];

$path = $_GET['path'];
$params = explode( "/", $path );
$site = array_shift($params);

if( in_array( $site, $sites ) ){
    include($site.".php");
}
```

Now in detail.php you can use `$params` and you get array with you values. So our `http://example.com/detail/56/1` goes like `http://example.com/index.php?path=detail/56/1`. With this aproach we will write our logic in details.php and we can use `$params`, which equals `Array ( [0] => 56 [1] => 1 )`.

Your link could be more readable in code if you change it to `/detail/id/56/subcat/11`. Just add this before check in_array

```
$x = [];
for( $i=0; $i<count($params); $i+=2 )
    $x[$params[$i]] = $params[$i+1];
$params = $x;
```

This is only simple example of idea. Better use some framework with that routing, like symphony.

Answer (score 2):

Just place the following into your .htaccess file (and make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php/([^/]+)/?([^/]*) /index.php?id=$1&subcat=$2 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following .htaccess sample file
**Note :** replace filename1 and filename2 with your php file names

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(filename1.*)$ filename1.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(filename2.*)$ filename2.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```